# How to test javascript in node repl (no browser)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, karma-runner, read-eval-print-loop

I have 2 files `mycode.js` and `mycode.test.js`. I want to test it in Node console (repl) - (no browser), in karma style.

**mycode.test.js**

```
var expect = require('expect');
var mycode = require("./mycode");

describe("mycode", () => {
    it("should properly run tests", () => {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

What is the simplest possible setup to achieve this?

Comment: Are you SURE you want to run this in the repl? That's not how most people run tests. They normally run tests simply using node.js. Not the repl

Comment: hi, yes i am sure i want to run test in node console -  means no browser. I am aware that tests are run mostly in browsers but i want simply to check if my code returns what i expect, ie. functionality that is not related to any browser settings.

Comment: You can run node.js programs in the console without the repl. They are two very different things.

Comment: If you look at drollwit's answer you will see the confusion caused by your intention to run the tests in the repl. Running tests in the repl is not how most people run tests. It is convoluted and complicated plus can't easily be automated. Running tests in node.js without a browser on the other hand is quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you could make that work in the node repl because a call to require() assumes you load that function separately, before loading the file you want to test. The only way I see of testing code in the repl is by having the function you are using to test included in the loaded file. For example, to test how function override works, you could create `function_override.js` and then load it into the repl --

`$ .load path/to/file/function_override.js`

-- and have an assert() function that is used to test the output of other functions inside that file. E.g.:

```
            function assert(value, text) {
              if (value === true) {
                  console.log(text);
              } else {
                  console.log ("that is false");
              }
            }

            var fun = 3;

            function FuncType1(){
              assert(typeof fun === "function", "We access the function");
            }

            function FuncType2(){
              var fun = 3;
              assert(typeof fun === "number", "Now we access the number");
            }

            function FuncType3(){
              assert(typeof fun === "number", "Still a number");
            }

            function fun(){};

            FuncType1(); // returns "We access the function"
            FuncType2(); // returns "Now we access the number"
            FuncType3(); // returns  "that is false"
```